# Disable keyboard navigation (Wordpress) when PrettyPhoto modal is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

I'm loading jQuery PrettyPhoto from a CDN. I've got this JS to enable post navigation from the keyboard:

```
  // Add keyboard navigation for the next & previous post buttons
  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var url = false;
    if (e.which == 37) { // Left arrow key code
      url = $('a.prev-post').attr('href'); // change to match the pagination link classes in your theme
    } else if (e.which == 39) { // Right arrow key code
      url = $('a.next-post').attr('href');
    }
    if (url) {
      window.location = url;
    }
  });
```

I'd like to add a boolean to prevent this code from executing when the PP modal is open, but I'm not sure how to go about it. The relevant code in PP is:

```
// Window/Keyboard events
$(window).unbind('resize.prettyphoto').bind('resize.prettyphoto',function(){ _center_overlay(); _resize_overlay(); });

if(pp_settings.keyboard_shortcuts) {
  $(document).unbind('keydown.prettyphoto').bind('keydown.prettyphoto',function(e){
    if(typeof $pp_pic_holder != 'undefined'){
      if($pp_pic_holder.is(':visible')){
        switch(e.keyCode){
          case 37:
            $.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
          case 39:
          $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
          e.preventDefault();
          break;
          case 27:
          if(!settings.modal)
            $.prettyPhoto.close();
            e.preventDefault();
            break;
        };
        // return false;
      };
    };
  });
};
```

I know I can do something like this on the post navigation:

```
  // Add keyboard navigation for the next & previous post buttons

 var canUseArrows = true;
 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var url = false;
    if (e.which == 37 && canUseArrows) { // Left arrow key code
      url = $('a.prev-post').attr('href'); // change to match the pagination link classes in your theme
    } else if (e.which == 39 && canUseArrows) { // Right arrow key code
      url = $('a.next-post').attr('href');
    }
    if (url) {
      window.location = url;
    }
  });
```

But I'm not sure how to hook into the PP function.

Thanks for looking,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to "hook into the PP function"; however, I've tried with the following, and it works for me:

```
  // Add keyboard navigation for the next & previous post buttons
  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var url = false,
      // Check if the modal is open/visible.
      canNavi = ! $('.pp_pic_holder').is(':visible');
    if (canNavi && e.which == 37) { // Left arrow key code
      url = $('a.prev-post').attr('href'); // change to match the pagination link classes in your theme
    } else if (canNavi && e.which == 39) { // Right arrow key code
      url = $('a.next-post').attr('href');
    }
    if (url) {
      window.location = url;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you; I will try that & let you know how it works out.

Comment: That works beautifully. I was clearly overthinking this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more efficient.

```
// Add keyboard navigation for the next & previous post buttons
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
var url = false,
// Check if the modal is open/visible.
canNavi = ( ! $( '.pp_pic_holder' ).length );
if (canNavi && e.which == 37) { // Left arrow key code
  url = $('a.prev-post').attr('href'); // change to match the pagination link classes in your theme
} else if (canNavi && e.which == 39) { // Right arrow key code
  url = $('a.next-post').attr('href');
}
if (url) {
  window.location = url;
}
```

});

From the jQuery documentation:

> - Because :visible is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :visible cannot take advantage of the
>     performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>     method. To achieve the best performance when using :visible to select
>     elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>     use .filter(":visible").
> - Using this selector heavily can have performance implications, as it may force the browser to re-render the page before it can determine
>     visibility. Tracking the visibility of elements via other methods,
>     using a class for example, can provide better performance.

Comment: That should be true for `$('.pp_pic_holder:visible')` (selecting elements), but not `$('.pp_pic_holder').is(':visible')` (filtering *selected* elements). Because I believe `.is(':visible')` is similar to `.filter(':visible')` (although the return value is different), which jQuery recommends when filtering the selected or matched elements. From the [`.is()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/is/), "*it allows you to test the contents of a jQuery object without modification*", which in our case, the object is `$('.pp_pic_holder')`.

Comment: However, if you'd rather simply check against the `length` property (i.e. `$( '.pp_pic_holder' ).length`), then I think the decision if all yours. =)